# How to use rust-openssl on iOS?

Tags: ios, gcc, rust, openssl

I'm trying to generate an RSA key pair: `Rsa::generate(4096)` with rust-openssl:

```
[dependencies]
openssl = { version = "0.10.30", features = ["vendored"] }
```

This is my build script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Ensure that `cargo` is in PATH, using the default location.
export PATH="$PATH:${HOME}/.cargo/bin"

# This obviously doesn't work for the app, only to build on desktop.
export OPENSSL_DIR="/usr/local/opt/openssl"

set -x

# Go to repo's root
cd "${SRCROOT}/../"

# Build binaries
RUSTFLAGS="-Z embed-bitcode" cargo +ios-arm64 build --target aarch64-apple-ios --release --lib
cargo build --target=x86_64-apple-ios --release

# Create fat binary
libtool -static -o ./ios_app/core/libcore ./target/aarch64-apple-ios/release/libcore.a ./target/x86_64-apple-ios/release/libcore.a
```

When the app is linking, it fails:

```
+ RUSTFLAGS='-Z embed-bitcode'
+ cargo +ios-arm64 build --target aarch64-apple-ios --release --lib
   Compiling openssl v0.10.30
   Compiling openssl-sys v0.9.58
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
.....
.....
.....
  = note: ld: library not found for -lSystem
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
          
error: aborting due to previous error
error: could not compile `openssl`.
```

[According to the docs](https://docs.rs/openssl/0.10.30/openssl/#vendored), for vendored OpenSSL I need a C compiler, perl and make installed:

> If the vendored Cargo feature is enabled, the openssl-src crate will be used to compile and statically link to a copy of OpenSSL. The build process requires a C compiler, perl, and make.

I checked: `gcc`, `perl` and `make` run in the terminal. The xcode tools also seem to be installed.

I also ran `brew update` and `brew upgrade gcc` (where I get `gcc 10.2.0 already installed`) (though this should be provided by the xcode tools).

Any ideas?

Comment: find in the iOS SDK `libSystem.a`, copy path to it, and add that path to OTHER_LDFLAGS

Comment: @EugeneDudnyk I couldn't find exactly `libSystem.a`. I found `libSystem.tbd`, `libSystem.B.tbd`, `libSystem_asan.tbd`, `libSystem.B_asan.tbd` (in `/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/lib/`. Added them all to `OTHER_LDFLAGS`. Getting the same error.

Comment: Also added the paths for the simulator (`/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform`)